# How to pass other class value to a set method

Tags: java, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin I want to set a vlue using setfunction. for example
in java we write code

```
 ResponseTemplateVO vo = new ResponseTemplateVO();
        User user = userRepository.findByUserId(userId);
 Department department =
                restTemplate.getForObject("http://DEPARTMENT-SERVICE/departments/" + user.getDepartmentId()
                        ,Department.class);

        vo.setUser(user);
        vo.setDepartment(department);

        return  vo;
```

my requirement is I want to set user and department value calling
setUser function and setDepartment function but I am not able to do
that

Her below my code i want my code working same as above java code

```
fun getUserWithDepartment(userId: Long): ResponseTemplateVO {
        val vo= ResponseTemplateVO()
        val userRegistration:UserRegistration=userRegistrationRepository.findUserById(userId)
        val department: Department? =
            restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9001/departments/"+userRegistration.departmentId,
            Department::class.java)
        vo.userRegistration
        vo.department
        return vo

    }
```

when I run this program I got blank page

Comment: `vo.user = user; vo.department = department`?

Comment: I already try this way but I don't know why i am getting blank page

Comment: What @AdamMillerchip says is 100% how you set properties in Kotlin, so if it's not working, it suggests there is some other problem

Comment: Please do not format your text as quote (edited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have experience in Kotlin,but i guess ResponseTemplateVO is a java POJO class so need to create a bean with variables of type User and Department

```
 public class ResponseTemplateVO {
  private User user;
  private Department department;
  //getter and setters
}
```

then you try to set objects to ResponseTemplateVO it will work.